# Redirect .cn .jp .ch .eu .fr to domain.com on lighttpd

Tags: regex, lighttpd

I would like to redirect several domains to our dotcom address.

The domains have the following extensions:

- cn
- jp
- ch
- eu
- fr

www.domain.fr should point to www.domain.com - sub.domain.fr should point to sub.domain.com and the path after the extension should stay intact so that www.domain.fr/foo points to www.domain.com/foo

FR is just an example. It should work for all extensions the way explained. For me, it does not matter wheter we explicitly write (cn|jp|ch|eu|fr) or if set a wildcard.

I tried the following which did not work:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(*.)?domain\.(*)(/*)?$" {
     url.redirect = ("^/(.*)" => "http://%1.domain.com%3")
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something's wrong with your regexp. (*) makes no sense whatsoever. I think you're more familiar with *glob* syntax. Just remember:

```
* (in glob) === .* (in regexp)
```

Basically `'.'` means anything and `'*'` means zero or more times of that anything. So I guess you want:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*\.)?domain\.(.*)$" {
    url.redirect = ("^(/.*)" => "http://%1.domain.com$1")
}
```

Note that plain dots need to be escaped `'\.'` because `'.'` means any character at all.

Also, remember that in lighttpd syntax, the `$HTTP["host"]` variable **does not contain any path**. You do the path extraction in the `url.redirect` part, not in the `$HTTP["host"]` part!

Comment: actually I am not familiar with both.. regex and glob.. that's why I combine them ;)

what do you  mean with "does not contain any path"? Because I want the www always at the beginning of the domain, the following code worked for me (also with host):
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ("^/(.*)" => "http://www.domain.com/$1")
}